# GNU Prolog : assert that list is ordered based on another list

Tags: prolog

I have two lists of integers, *Xs*, and *Ys*. I want to assert the following using GNU :

For *i,j* such that *Xs*[*i*]=*Xs*[*j*], *i* < *j* implies *Ys*[*i*]<*Ys*[*j*].

Any help would be appreciated!

*Note : such an assertion would be possible since *Ys* is made up of integers that are all different.*

Comment: Not really specific to GNU Prolog, removed GNU Prolog tag. (Actually, you want a proper theorem prover for this )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
neg_ass(Xs, Ys) :-
    nth0(I, Xs, X),
    nth0(J, Xs, X),
    I < J,
    nth0(I, Ys, YI),
    nth0(J, Ys, YJ),
    YI >= YJ.
    
assertion(Xs, Ys) :-
   \+neg_ass(Xs, Ys).
```

Comment: "The assertion is TRUE if an exhaustive search does not provide a counterexample" 